# Change interal HDD to SSD inside ThinkPad T520 with locked BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios, thinkpad

I use a Lenovo ThinkPad T520 and it's BIOS is locked

The Notebook uses a 500GB HDD and I want to buy another storage device (a SSD).

The BIOS settings are locked. Will I have to expect problems with the system respectively the BIOS to recognize the changed device?

Comment: If you simply intend to clone the old drive to the new then it will operate without any trouble.

Comment: If you're up for it, you can reset the EEPROM that controls the supervisor password. http://www.ja.axxs.net/t520.htm

Answer (score 0):

Nope, i wouldnt expect so. In case you are allowed to change the harddrive without entering the password at all, the only problem left is the "AHCI vs IDE" setting in the BIOS. Setting to AHCI would slightly improve the life duration of your new SSD harddrive but

- it might be already set to ahci
- setting to ahci should be totally optional anyway

Comment: It is set to AHCI already, I‘m lucky :). I inserted another harddrive today and the openSUSE installer displayed it‘s old partitions. However I didn’t test booting. So that‘s the way I can test it, isn‘t it?

Comment: Sure, the harddrive has been recognized so there are no issues with your BIOS password. What are your afraid of?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you try to remove the password, or you may get into trouble with
the new disk.

I found this video tutorial that explains how to remove the password by
hardware manipulation:

[How to unlock BIOS Supervisor Password from Lenovo Thinkpad Laptop (no damage to laptop)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FW-RLkzjAS8)

Just be careful if you decide to follow it.

Answer (score -1):

I successfully changed my internal HDD to a SSD without any issues regarding the locked BIOS of my ThinkPad T520.

Comment: I wanted to share my evidence based experience with the answer. Is this relevant respectively auxiliary?